# looping through a firebase document and converting the list into pages/widgets

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to loop through a document in firebase and convert each individual data into a page view.

This is my code where I got the snapshot of the document and each document has list of data, but I don't want to call them individually but loop through the necessary document data to add them to a page view. How do I go about this?

```
StreamBuilder(
stream:
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('book').snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapShot) {
  if (!snapShot.hasData) {
    print('no data found');
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else {
    final books = snapShot.data!.docs;
    List<NewStoryWidgets> list = [];
    for (var book in books) {
      final authName = book.data()['authName'];
      final title = book.data()['title'];
      final chapterNum = book.data()['chapterNum'];

      final card = NewStoryWidgets(
        title: title,
        auth: authName,
        rating: 4,
        pressDetail: () {},
        pressRead: () {},
        image: 'image/7.jpg',
      );
      for (int i = 0; i < chapterNum; i++) {
        List chap = [];
        final text = book.data()['$i'];
        chap.add(text);
        print(chap);
      }
      list.add(card);
    }
      return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: list,
    );
  }
}),
```